# i like to check whether a number is prime or not. i have the code but its working partially

Tags: java

//method 2. to check for prime numbers.

```
public boolean primecheck(int number)
    {  
        for(int i=2;2*i<number;i++){
            if(number % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I'm getting the following output for numbers 2 to 20 as below:

[image]

Comment: `2*i<number` should be `i*i<=number`.

Comment: You need to break the loop when condition for prime is met.

Comment: @JunedAhsan the return will exit the loop (and the method)

Comment: thank you #Elliott Frisch, #juned Ahsan and #ross bille

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the loop termination and prime check conditions.

```
boolean flag=true;
        for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
        {
            if(n%i==0)
            {
                flag=false;
                break;
            }
            else
                flag=true;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("given number is prime");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("given number is not prime");
        }
```

Comment: thank you. the code works fine with the loop- (for i=2;i*i<=number;i++)

Comment: hai, in this case you need to check the loop up to number/2 times. because after number/2 the same conditions are repeating . Also it reduces loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, which checks if a number is prime.

```
public boolean primecheck(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
        if(n%i==0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this again gives different out. totally wrong. the output i am getting is fine but except on input. for number as 4 it should return false, because its not a prime. but i am getting true as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the loop condition to

```
public boolean primecheck(int number)
    {  
        for(int i=2;i*i<=number;i++){
            if(number % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: thank you #Tushar Gupta. now it works fine.